# Hacer update desde un function en php

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo el siguiente código con el cual obtengo un rango de fechas desde y hasta

```
$año = date('Y');
$fechainicio = "2020-09-01";
$fechafin = "2020-09-30";
foreach (getDiasHabiles($fechainicio, $fechafin, 
[ 
    //Poner a partir de aca todas las fechas feriadas
    "$año-09-30",
    "$año-09-07" 


]) as $fecha_feriados) {
}
function getDiasHabiles($fechainicio, $fechafin, $diasferiados = array()) {
        // Convirtiendo en timestamp las fechas
        $fechainicio = strtotime($fechainicio);
        $fechafin = strtotime($fechafin);
       
        // Incremento en 1 dia
        $diainc = 24*60*60;
       
        // Arreglo de dias habiles, inicianlizacion
        $diashabiles = array();
       
        // Se recorre desde la fecha de inicio a la fecha fin, incrementando en 1 dia
        for ($midia = $fechainicio; $midia <= $fechafin; $midia += $diainc) {
                // Si el dia indicado, no es sabado o domingo es habil
                if (!in_array(date('N', $midia), array(6,7))) { // DOC: http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.date.php
                        // Si no es un dia feriado entonces es habil
                        if (!in_array(date('Y-m-d', $midia), $diasferiados)) {
                                array_push($diashabiles, date('Y-m-d', $midia));
                        }
                }
        }
       
        echo $diashabiles[12];
$actualizar = mysqli_query(conexion,"UPDATE solicitudes SET f1 = '$diashabiles[0]', f2 = '$diashabiles[1]', f3 = '$diashabiles[2]' WHERE cedula = '$cedula' AND fecha_solicitud = '$fecha_solicitud'");
}
```

Aqui le hago un echo para ver si me esta trayendo bien algun dato, la cosa es que al momento de actualizar no hace nada, las variables $cedula y $fecha_solicitud vienen de un post ya por alli estoy bien, si intento cambiar las variables por datos fijos aun asi no lo actualiza, que puede estar pasando?

Comment: Saludos, comienza por colocarle el símbolo $ a la variable conexión en la penúltima línea. Además por favor coloca el error que te está arrojando, de esa forma la comunidad te puede ayudar más rápido a resolver el problema.

Comment: huy perdon no me di cuenta de eso, mas sin embargo no me muestra ningun error, queda en blanco

Comment: Si definitivamente, por alguna razon dentro de function no me quiere hacer el update, porque?

Comment: Lo primero que debes enfocarte es en tener un codigo con el que puedas ver los errores, si no tienes una forma de verlos imposible saber como corregirlos, trata de utilizar try catchs o crear validacion en torno a la ejecución de tus querys.

Comment: Prueba colocando algunas de estas funciones al incio de la ejecución de tu script para ver si te  muestra algun error. `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`
`ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);` `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: Muchas gracias fue de utilidad, la variable de conexion no me la estaba tomando, ahora que la ingrese directamente a la funcion me lo tomo, gracias

Comment: Ok entonces  agregaré la respuesta y por favor selecciona como correcta la respuesta que resolvió el problema.

Comment: Vale, si no lo hago hoy te prometo que mañana lo are, ya que me voy